# How to combine each of the elements of two lists

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

First of all i'd like to thank you for viewing the question. I'm new to vb.net and i'm trying to combine elements in two arraylist. For example i have arraylist 1 that has 3 elements: Jim, Joe, Tom and a second arraylist that has 4 elements: Winter, Summer, Autumn, Spring.

Now, i want to take each element from arraylist1 and each element from arraylist 2, so i'll have: 
Jim Winter, 
Jim, Summer, 
Jim Autumn, 
Jim Spring, 
Joe Winter, 
Joe Summer 
etc.

I've mananged to do this with a nested For each, but what i want is to also get a result with combined elements from arraylist2, something like this: 
Jim Winter Summer, 
Jim Winter Autumn, 
Jim Winter Spring, 
Jim Winter Summer Autumn
Jim Winter Summer Autumn Spring

this is the code i wrote (please ignore the fact that i am using listboxes.items)

```
For Each item As String In lst_infractiuni.Items
        Lst_generare_infr1.lst_gen_infractiuni_imp.Items.Add(item)

        For Each item2 As String In lst_pv.Items
            Lst_generare_infr1.lst_gen_infractiuni_imp.Items.Add(item & item2)
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: What kind of type is: "Lst_generare_infr1"   ...the "Dim as"....

Comment: The elements are strings

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off
Module Module1
    Private Sub ArraysUnion()
        Dim A As String() = {"Jim", "Joe", "Tom"}
        Dim B As String() = {"Winter", "Summer", "Autumn", "Spring"}
        Dim C As String() = A.Union(B).ToArray
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(";", C))
    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        ArraysUnion()
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this will only combine the arrays giving something like: Jim; Joe; Tom; Winter; Summer; Autumn. What i want is to  take element 1 from A (in your example) and combine it with every single element in B. So the results should be something like : Jim Winter, Jim Summer, Jim Autumn, Jim Spring, Jim Winter Summer, Jim Winter Autumn and so on. The point is that i want to automatically generated combination